# Touch detection with UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, touch

I am facing a problem in using `UIButton` action and `touchesmoved`. The scenario is, when I drag my fingers over a series of buttons its actions should be called.I button can be touched individually as well.

I used the `touchesmoved` method to find out the touch points on uibutton to trigger its action. The problem with that approach is, When I tap somewhere in view and move my finger over button everything works, but if I start my touch on UIButton itself `touchesmoved` method is not called.

Comment: Sounds like you implemented touchesMoved in the UIView that contains all the buttons. So the view has a implementation of touchesMoved. Now, when you start in the button, the button does not have an instance of touchesMoved, so it doesn't call any function and nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below, will be helpful for you.

[Handling touch events for UIButtons in iPhone](http://sree.cc/iphone/handling-touche-events-for-uibuttons-in-iphone)

[Is there a way to pass touches through on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631427/is-there-a-way-to-pass-touches-through-on-the-iphone)

[touchesBegin & touchesMove Xcode Obj C Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050184/touchesbegin-touchesmove-xcode-obj-c-question)

Comment: Thanks, I have used the second link to pass the touch event.Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know the exact location of the touch, just when they swiped over it, you can add a target to it and use one of the many UIControlEvents, like UIControlEventTouchDragInside, etc.

Here's the full enum straight from `UIControl.h`

```
enum {
    UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,      // on all touch downs
    UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,      // on multiple touchdowns (tap count > 1)
    UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
    UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
    UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
    UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
    UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
    UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
    UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

    UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,     // sliders, etc.

    UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,     // UITextField
    UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
    UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
    UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing

    UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,  // for touch events
    UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,  // for UITextField
    UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,  // range available for application use
    UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,  // range reserved for internal framework use
    UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
typedef NSUInteger UIControlEvents;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time answer the question. I solved my issue.